# List industry segment members using FinancialData

Tags: curated-data, finance

I'm trying to select get price, div yield and PE ratios for a given Sector (Industrial Segment) from the LSE. At the moment I'm trying to just get a list of the companies

Unfortunately my script is pulling all Shares on the LSE, and not just those in the Banking Sector as seen in the snippet below.

[image]

Comment: Please post actual code rather than just a screen shot.  Makes it easier for everyone to help.

Comment: Thanks , lack of experience on my part. I tried that but there was an error and it was rejected.

Answer (score 2):

Filter the exchange from the members of the sector

```
symbols = FinancialData["BanksRegional", "Members"] // Select[StringStartsQ["L:"]]
```

Symbol to name `Association`

```
names = AssociationMap[FinancialData[#, "Name"] &, symbols]
```

Price for May, unfortunately, it is `Missing["NotAvailable"]` for several symbols.

```
may2021Prices = AssociationMap[FinancialData[#, "Price", {{2021, 5, 1}, {2021, 5, 30}}] &, symbols]
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this answer! (+1) I think OP is interested in all of these three properties: `{"Price", "PERatio", "DividendYield"}`; last two are not provided by `FinancialData`. For example, see the output of: `FinancialData["L:AIBG", {"Price", "PERatio", 
  "DividendYield"}, {{2021, 5, 1}, {2021, 5, 30}}]`.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Hi Anton, `FinancialData` is quite incomplete for markets outside the US. WRI is aware of this but there has not been much progress on improving the situation. I suspect that it is quite expensive to obtain and curate this data.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. I was thinking about trying to use the L: as field separator of somesort. Thanks I'll give it a try.

Comment: Thanks Anton & Rohit. Yes I've noticed that the data for non-US exchanges is not as fullsome as that of the USA. Which is why I'm wondering if I may have to pull data from Yahoo/Google or some other source